# Using EasyMock with TestNG

Tags: junit, testng, easymock

I know there two ways to use the "Mock" and the "TestSubject" annotations with JUnit. The first one - is to specify the EasyMockLoader class object for the RunWith annotation for the class that contains fields marked by these annotations. The second one - is to mark the EasyMockRule field with the "Rule" annotation. How to use the "Mock" and the "TestSubject" annotations with TestNG ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TestNG is not directly supported. But you can inject mocks using the annotations quite easily by doing

```
EasyMockSupport.injectMocks(this);
```

(from your test class)

Comment: I'm working on a native integration of TestNG: https://github.com/easymock/easymock/pull/186

Comment: It works but it should be `EasyMockSupport.injectMocks(this);`.

Answer (score 1):

As I known, EasyMock doesn't support TestNG out of the box but PowerMock does.
Maybe using PowerMock + EasyMock + TestNG will work like a charm.

Otherwise, about `@Mock`, you'll have to manage it by yourself (looking for fields, creating mock and injecting them) with [a configuration method](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations) (a `@BeforeX` method) or [an appropriate listener](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners).
Another solution could be to use [the Guice integration](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#guice-dependency-injection) and making mocks in a Guice module.

Same  solution for `@TestSubject`: configuration methods or listeners.